# Identify element based on element outside of <div> tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to use Selenium and XPATH to click on an element that is not uniquely identifiable, but the title of box in which it's contained is uniquely identifiable. I want to click on a dropdown box within the "Date" box, but the "Date" title is outside the div tag of the dropdown box.

Here's the html: [image: html]
I want to click on the highlighted row, but identify the row by the red underlined "Date" text within the span tag. The source html may change, so a simple xpath does not work. Is that possible?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you try this css selector? `input.input-text[type=text][readonly=readonly][title]` Moreover, can you share the url?

Comment: That didn't work. There are multiple dropdown boxes with identical html on the page.